# Error with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

When I try the magic command %pylab I get the following error:

```
In [1]: %pylab
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5c1faa999e5b> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'pylab')

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2203         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2204         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2205         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2206 
   2207     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2124                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2125             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2126                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2127             return result
   2128 

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in pylab(self, line)

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in pylab(self, line)
    134             import_all = not args.no_import_all
    135 
--> 136         gui, backend, clobbered = self.shell.enable_pylab(args.gui, import_all=import_all)
    137         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
    138         print ("Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib")

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all, welcome_message)
   2980         from IPython.core.pylabtools import import_pylab
   2981 
-> 2982         gui, backend = self.enable_matplotlib(gui)
   2983 
   2984         # We want to prevent the loading of pylab to pollute the user's

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2941                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   2942 
-> 2943         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   2944         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   2945 

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    287     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    288 
--> 289     import matplotlib.pyplot
    290     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    291 

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.p in <module>()
     25 
     26 import matplotlib
---> 27 import matplotlib.colorbar
     28 from matplotlib import style
     29 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>()
     32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     36 import matplotlib.contour as contour

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in <module>()
     25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     29 from matplotlib import _path

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in <module>()
     54 
     55 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 56 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     57 from matplotlib.path import Path
     58 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py in <module>()
     17 from matplotlib.path import Path
     18 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 19 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     20 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     21 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
   1410                 verbose.report("Using fontManager instance from %s" % _fmcache)
   1411         except:
-> 1412             _rebuild()
   1413     else:
   1414         _rebuild()

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in _rebuild()
   1395     def _rebuild():
   1396         global fontManager
-> 1397         fontManager = FontManager()
   1398         if _fmcache:
   1399             pickle_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in __init__(self, size, weight)
   1035         #  Load TrueType fonts and create font dictionary.
   1036 
-> 1037         self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
   1038         self.defaultFamily = {
   1039             'ttf': 'Bitstream Vera Sans',

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in findSystemFonts(fontpaths, fontext)
    320                     fontfiles[f] = 1
    321 
--> 322             for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
    323                 fontfiles[f] = 1
    324 

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext)
    272         pipe = subprocess.Popen(['fc-list', '--format=%{file}\\n'],
    273                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
--> 274                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    275         output = pipe.communicate()[0]
    276     except (OSError, IOError):

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    708                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    709                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
--> 710                                 errread, errwrite)
    711         except Exception:
    712             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

/Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
   1325                         raise
   1326                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
-> 1327                 raise child_exception
   1328 
   1329 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have uninstalled and installed matplotlib again many times. I am using the latest versions of IPython and Matplotlib in my Mac OS Mavericks.

What else should I try?

Tks

Comment: how did you install matplotlib? which version of python? where is python installed?

Comment: I installed mpl using pip. Python 2.7 using Anaconda. Directory: /Users/rafaelrodrigues/anaconda/lib/python2.7

Comment: If you have conda, then you should use it to install libraries from the scientific Python ecosystem.

Comment: I started having a very similar issue after an update (conda 3.7.2), anaconda (2.1.0). My error message says `TypeError: cannot return std::string from Unicode object`, again something to do with the `FontManager`. Any luck in figuring out what's wrong so far?

Comment: UPDATE: manually running `conda install matplotlib` solved my problem. For some reason `conda update anaconda` does not fetch the latest versions of matplotlib and associated packages.

Comment: what does import sys; print sys.getdefaultencoding() showing?

Comment: @denfromufa: `ascii`

Comment: did you try with unicode, e.g.: import sys; sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

Comment: or import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')

Comment: @denfromufa - Wow, thank you for the prompt reply. That gave me an error: 

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-385cd9a6cfb1> in <module>()
----> 1 import sys; sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'`

Comment: @denfromufa: Error `TypeError: cannot return std::string from Unicode object` still persists. My code is still identical to the OP except the blocks of code after the one containing `FontManager()` are slightly different. If you would prefer discussing this in Chat, let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73501/discussion-between-denfromufa-and-clarinetist).

Answer (score 1):

activate your conda environment if you're not using the default environment, then do `conda install matplotlib`

Comment: unfortunately, it still does not work using conda install matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

@Clarinetist:

1. try with fresh official Python installation.
2. setup ipython notebook server according to this guide:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/notebook.html

3. pylab is discouraged:

http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related